# Bug when adding li content to ul using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following problem when adding list items to an **ul** using javascript code: I'm trying to add a list item to a ul, which is added and displayed for a fraction of a second before disappearing.
This is the code for adding the item to **ul** in **file1.js**:

```
function isValidForm() {
addContentToUl("item1");
}

function addContentToUl(error) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("errorList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(error));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

This is the line of code for calling the function in **file2.js**:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = isValidForm;
```

And the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My first PIU lab</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="BaroiuCezar_Lab1.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="file1.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
        <form id="myForm" action="">
            <ul id="errorList"></ul>
            <p>Numele</p>
            <input id="idLastname" type="text" name="lastName" />
            <p>Prenumele</p>
            <input id="IdFirstName" type="text" name="firstName" />
            <p>Adresa</p>
            <input id="idAddress" type="text" name="address" />
            <p>Data nasterii</p>
            <input id="idBirthday" type="text" name="birthDate" />
            <p>Telefon</p>
            <input id="idPhone" type="text" name="phoneNumber" />
            <p>Email</p>
            <input id="idEmail" type="text" name="email" />
            <section>
                <span>Culoarea favorita</span>
                <input id="idColor" type="color" name="color" />
            </section>
            <br /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Trimite" />
            <input type="submit" value="Reseteaza" />
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="file2.js"></script>
    </div>
```

The added item should be displayed in the first **ul** after the **form** element.

Comment: You should prevent default form submission behaviour when adding event handler to submit action. The page is refreshing probably.

Comment: In addition to @sabithpocker's recommendation, note that you have no element with ID `errorList`.  Perhaps change `<ul>` to `<ul id="errorList">`?

Comment: You need to prevent the default behavior for onsubmit, to stop the page from refreshing, that is why it is disappearing.

Comment: How can I prevent the page to refresh using only JavaScript and not jQuery? Thanks

Comment: Is `jQuery` not `javascript` ??? Or you mean something different ??

Comment: You could also just change the `input`s to have `type="button"` instead of `submit`.

Comment: You can add event listener to submit event and return false to prevent page to be refreshed using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```
function isValidForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//disable default form submission by browser.
    addContentToUl("item1");
}

function addContentToUl(error) {
    var ul = document.getElementById("errorList");
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(error));
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `submit` function which is `isValidForm` should return `false` to prevent the form from submitting. Like below

```
function isValidForm() {
   addContentToUl("item1");
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know that!